# Use Multiple Image Editors in Compositor

Tags: compositing-nodes

I was looking into the compositor for the first time, but I came across something that is an issue. There seems to be no way to view multiple outputs from the node tree.Both image viewers just show whatever the most recent viewer I clicked on is.
Am I correct in this or am I doing something incorrect here?
[image: Comp_Example]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You’re doing everything right.
This is just the way Blender works.

Here’s how you can make it work:
1) In one image editor choose *Render Result* from the top-down menu. This will show output from the *Compositor Node.*
2) In the other one choose *Viewer Node* to see output from selected *Viewer Node*.

As you noticed, *Viewer Node* only shows the last selected one. It’s a limitation of Blender.
However, you can use *Split Viewer Node* node to get side-by-side comparison.

*How to make it work*
[image: *enter image description here*]

Note:
Blender Compositor has some slight limitations, but hey, it’s free :).

Comment: "Note: Blender Compositor has some slight limitations, but hey, it’s free :)." 
That's a definite plus. But I'm looking at this for our studio, so it's needs to meet certain standards if we're going to use it ;)

I tried what you suggested but the Render Result is showing nothing.
Hopefully the compositor will get some attention and have things like this addressed :)

Comment: @Anti-Distinctlyminty I share your pain - Blender Compositor would seriously deserve more friendly UI. That’s why I switched to other software for compositing.

Comment: I've been very impressed with Natron. But it looks dead in the water, which is a real shame.

Comment: Some people use DaVinci for compositing, as it supports EXR files and is also node based. I believe Blender Compositor could learn a lot from their UI.